# How to do a non-greedy lstrip()

Tags: python

I am doing the following:

```
'm:max'.lstrip('m:')
'ax'
```

What I need to get is remove the `"m:"` only. I have a lot of other combinations, which I am using to filter search results -- for example`"g:Holiday` would search a particular category for "Holiday".

Also, sometimes there is no prefix, which would mean it would search all categories.

How would I do this?

Comment: `'m:max'[2:]`? Do you always know there is a two-char prefix?

Comment: What are the rules here?  Are you always trimming the first 2 characters?  Is the first colon in the string always the delimiter?  Is there always a piece you are looking to trim?

Comment: There's some implied background here that defines the scope and requirements of this problem that you elude to in your question without specifying, making it pretty hard to come up with a useful answer.  For example, what are "categories" and who or what is searching them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way I could figure out how to accomplish the above:

```
re.sub(r'^[a-z]:','',string)
```

Comment: This will match colons in the middle of a string.

Comment: You might want to anchor it with a `^`.

Answer (score 8):

You are not 100% clear on what the rules are, but if it's simply an issue of removing everything before the first colon, then you can use `split`:

```
>>> 'm:abc'.split(':',1)[-1]
'abc'
>>> 'mabc'.split(':',1)[-1]
'mabc'
>>> 'm:a:bc'.split(':',1)[-1]
'a:bc'
```

The second argument to `split` limits the number of splits to perform, and the `[-1]` gets the right part of the split (or the first element if there are no splits).

See [the documentation on `str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

If, however, the colon *must* be in second position:

```
def remove_prefix(s):
    return s[2:] if len(s) > 1 and s[1] == ':' else s
```

Comment: Using this method will also strip `'bob:'` from `'bob:abc'`.  If that's acceptable, then this works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Keep it simple.

```
prefix = 'm:'
if a.startswith(prefix):
   a = a[len(prefix):]
```

---

BTW

```
'm:max'.lstrip('m:')
```

this is wrong; lstrip takes a set of characters to strip (order is irrelevant), not an initial substring to optionally strip.

Comment: But, but but ... I thought that OP had already realized how `lstrip` was wrong.  The question was what to do about it.